# Simple query table search filter

Tags: jquery, search, filter

The blow is a basic filter search for tables.  Currently it filters and searches the entire table (thead & tbody).  Is there any way to make this script search just the tbody?  I want to exclude the thead from the filtered results and I've tried appending the "id="kwd_search"" to just the  instead of the  tag, but it makes the script not function.  Another I would like it not to do is scale the table rows smaller when it finds results.

Any help is greatly appreciated and thanks for reading.  [Here is a live demo of what I have](http://jsfiddle.net/aPLLF/).  I'm really slow with this stuff, so I would really be nice if I could get a live example back if it isn't much trouble.

```
// When document is ready: this gets fired before body onload <img src='http://blogs.digitss.com/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_smile.gif' alt=':)' class='wp-smiley' /> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Write on keyup event of keyword input element
    $("#kwd_search").keyup(function(){
        // When value of the input is not blank
        if( $(this).val() != "")
        {
            // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
            $("#my-table tbody>tr").hide();
            $("#my-table td:contains-ci('" + $(this).val() + "')").parent("tr").show();
        }
        else
        {
            // When there is no input or clean again, show everything back
            $("#my-table tbody>tr").show();
        }
    });
});
// jQuery expression for case-insensitive filter
$.extend($.expr[":"], 
{
    "contains-ci": function(elem, i, match, array) 
    {
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || $(elem).text() || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I didn't feel like debugging the `contains-ci` approach. Can replace it with `filter()`

```
// When document is ready: this gets fired before body onload <img src='http://blogs.digitss.com/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_smile.gif' alt=':)' class='wp-smiley' /> 
$(document).ready(function() {
     /* cache td elements to improve search performance*/
      var $rows=$("#my-table tbody>tr"), $cells=$rows.children();
    // Write on keyup event of keyword input element
    $("#kwd_search").keyup(function() {
        var term = $(this).val()
        // When value of the input is not blank
        if(term != "") {
            // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
            $rows.hide();
            $cells.filter(function() {
                return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1;
            }).parent("tr").show();
        } else {
            // When there is no input or clean again, show everything back
            $rows.show();
        }
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/aPLLF/2/